# Request blocked by CORS policy: Header field is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers

Tags: rest, axios

I am using Axios to make a POST request with the following headers:

```
let reqConf = {
    headers: {
      'x-xsrf-token': '....',
      'Content-Type': 'Application/json',
      'Access-Control-Request-Headers': 'content-type',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, x-xsrf-token'
     }  
}
```

I make a post call like so: `const response = await axios.post(url, request, reqConf )' I get the following error message:` Request blocked by CORS policy: Request Header x-xsrf-token field  is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers`, but if I remove that header from my request I still get the same error but for other headers such as Content-Type.

I have modified the server config to allow `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"`. I have set `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` with all of my headers and my OPTIONS call returns 200 in browser. Is there something else I am missing in my request?